# Error when combining a subquery in a NSPredicate with valueForKeyPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I store time periods in Core Data. Each time period has an `DateTime` attribute called EndDate. I am trying to get the maximum end date, which is before (`<`) the date specified.

[image: Financial period]

This is how I have coded this using a subquery and ValueForKeyPath:

```
NSString *keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(SELF, $x, $x.EndDate < %@).@max.EndDate", date];
IBFinPeriod *periodBeforeCurrentDate = [self.finperiod valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
```

However, when running this code, I get the runtime error: `the entity IBFinPeriod is not key value coding-compliant for the key "SUBQUERY(SELF, $x, $x".'`

What is wrong with my code? 
Do I need to specify the subquery differently?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a fetch request with `fetchLimit` set to 1 and a descending sort descriptor.

If you insist on the `valueForKeyPath:` I would first filter the results with `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` (with a straight forward predicate selecting the records with dates prior to your `date`) and then simply using `@"@max.EndDate"` as the key path.

If you need the entire object rather than just the date, just sort your set:

```
NSSet *periodsBeforeCurrentDate = [self.finperiod 
    filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"EndDate < %@", date]];
if (periodsBeforeCurrentDate.count) {
    *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"EndDate" ascending:NO];
   NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
   IBFinPeriod *lastPeriodBeforeCurrentDate =[[periodsBeforeCurrentDate 
       sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

In my opinion it would be easier to just fetch.

Comment: I have tried `NSSet *periodsBeforeCurrentDate = [self.finperiod filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"EndDate < %@", date]];
    IBFinPeriod *lastPeriodBeforeCurrentDate =[periodsBeforeCurrentDate valueForKeyPath:@"@max.EndDate"];`. However, with this valueForKeyPath statement I do get only the date attribute `EndDate` but not the full time period entity. How would I need to set the keyPath to get the time period object and not only the value for its attribute `EndDate`?

Comment: You could just stick with the array functions - see above.

Comment: Thank you for the code sample, Mundi. I was trying to optimize for performance as I am calling this method > 3000 times (I have 11 time periods per company in my Core Data "database"). Filtering and sorting seemed to be too CPU intensive. Is your filtering and sorting code being executed directly on the database as SQL statements or in-memory?

Comment: This would be in memory. So I am not surprised at the performance hit. You should go with my first recommendation using fetch requests. Then it's all SQLite native and very fast.